# Evaluate $\int _0^{\infty }\frac{e^{-t^2}-e^{-4t^2}}{t^2}dt$

Tags: calculus, integration, functions

As my title says, I need help integrating
$$\int _0^{\infty }\frac{e^{-t^2}-e^{-4t^2}}{t^2}dt$$

How would approach this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *Hint.* Integration by parts!

Comment: @SangchulLee Oh now I see. solved! Thanks a lot:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**:

By parts,

$$\int _0^{\infty }\frac{e^{-t^2}-e^{-4t^2}}{t^2}dt=-\frac{e^{-t^2}-e^{-4t^2}}{t}+\int _0^{\infty }\frac{-2te^{-t^2}+8te^{-4t^2}}{t}dt.$$

Comment: I have additional question regarding this problem. Thank you. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2362486/463657

Comment: @KDRL: sorry, not working made-to-order.

Comment: Oh I understand. If it is rude, I am really sorry.

Comment: @KDRL: no problem, I am just telling you.