# Evaluating $\int_0^\infty x^{-2}e^{-x^2} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, functions

I am trying to solve the question below.
$$\int _0^{\infty }\frac{e^{-t^2}-e^{-4t^2}}{t^2}dt$$
And I asked here([Evaluate $\int _0^{\infty }\frac{e^{-t^2}-e^{-4t^2}}{t^2}dt$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2362382/463657)) and got a hint.
$$\int _0^{\infty }\frac{e^{-t^2}-e^{-4t^2}}{t^2}dt=[-\frac{e^{-t^2}-e^{-4t^2}}{t}]_0^\infty +\int _0^{\infty }\frac{-2te^{-t^2}+8te^{-4t^2}}{t}dt=0$$
The boundary term appearing from integration by parts vanish.(Using l'hopital's rule)

> In addtion, now I am trying to evaluate 
>   $$\int_0^\infty t^{-2}e^{-t^2} dt$$
>    with the same approach(Integration by part and using l'hopital's rule for boundary term).

$$\int_0^\infty t^{-2}e^{-t^2} dt = [-\frac{e^{-t^2}}{t}]_0^\infty -2 \int_0^\infty e^{-t^2} dt = -\sqrt\pi$$

But I feel something wrong. Because $t^{-2}e^{-t^2}$ is positive in $[0,\infty)$, the value must be positive. I want to find my error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think your integration may have a mistake (I would expect the error function to appear).  But anyway perhaps the integral is infinite/diverges (look near $0$)

Comment: your integral doesn't converge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integral $\int_0^\infty t^{-2}e^{-t^2} dt$ does not converge (the integrad is equivalent to $1/t^2$ in a right neighborhood of $0$).
Note that
$$\int _0^{\infty }\frac{-2te^{-t^2}+8te^{-4t^2}}{t}dt=-2\int _0^{\infty }e^{-t^2}dt+8\int _0^{\infty }e^{-4t^2}dt\\=-2\int _0^{\infty }e^{-t^2}dt+8\int _0^{\infty }e^{-s^2}d(s/2)=(4-2)\int _0^{\infty }e^{-t^2}dt=\sqrt{\pi}$$
where in the last step we used the [Gaussian integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral).

Answer (score 1):

As Robert Z answered, the problem is around $t=0$.

Just to see how does the result behaves, et us compute $$I=\int_\epsilon^\infty\frac{e^{-t^2}}{t^2}\,dt$$ Using integration by parts, you should arrive to $$I=\frac{e^{-\epsilon ^2}}{\epsilon }-\sqrt{\pi }\, \text{erfc}(\epsilon )$$ where appears the [complementary error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function#Complementary_error_function).

Developed as series around $\epsilon=0$, you should end with $$I=\frac{1}{\epsilon }-\sqrt{\pi }+\epsilon +O\left(\epsilon
   ^2\right)$$

Just to check, let $\epsilon=10^{-k}$ and compute the exact and approximated values of the integral for six significant figures.
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 k & \text{exact} & \text{approximation}\\
 1 & 8.32738 & 8.32755 \\
 2 & 98.2375 & 98.2375 \\
 3 & 998.229 & 998.229 \\
 4 & 9998.23 & 9998.23
\end{array}
\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

To use a divergent integral to compute a convergent one is in general a bad idea.
You may simply notice that
$$ I(1,4)=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-t^2}-e^{-4t^2}}{t^2}\,dt\stackrel{t\mapsto\sqrt{x}}{=}\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-x}-e^{-4x}}{x\sqrt{x}}\,dx $$
and since $\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{2x\sqrt{x}}\right)=\sqrt{\frac{s}{\pi}} $ by [a useful property of the Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Evaluating_integrals_over_the_positive_real_axis) we have:
$$\begin{eqnarray*} I(1,4)&=&\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{1}{1+s}-\frac{1}{4+s}\right)\sqrt{s}\,ds\\&\stackrel{s\to u^2}{=}&\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{u^2}{(1+u^2)(4+u^2)}\,du \end{eqnarray*}$$
and by partial fraction decomposition we have the more general result:

> $$ \forall A,B>0, \qquad I(A,B)=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-At^2}-e^{-Bt^2}}{t^2}\,dt = \color{blue}{\sqrt{\pi}\left(\sqrt{B}-\sqrt{A}\right)}. $$